# Defining multiple decision variables of the same type in a row in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

Is there any way for defining multiple decision variables of the same type in a row in CPLEX? For example, Something like:

```
dvar float+ var1 var2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dvar float+ var[1..2];
```

works fine

```
range r;
dvar float+ var[r];
```

is even better

And if you need to use one line

```
dvar int x; dvar int y;

subject to
{
  x+y<=2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if they are different symbols? Like x and y.